# Does Thunder Hooves Rage damage stack with itself?

Tags: dnd-4e, powers, movement, barbarian

Can a barbarian move back and forth through an enemy space to stack **Thunder Hooves** damage?

> ### Thunder Hooves Rage
>
> **Daily**
>   **Standard Action**      **Melee** Weapon
>
> **Target:** One Creature
>   **Keywords:** Primal, Rage, Weapon
>   **Attack:** Strength vs. AC
>   **Hit:** 3[W] + Str modifier damage.
>
> **Miss:** Half damage.
>
> **Effect:** You enter the rage of the thunder hooves.
>   Until the rage ends, you can move through one or two enemies' spaces during
>   each of your turns.
>   When you move through an enemy's space, your next attack against that enemy
>   during the same turn deals 1[W] extra Damage.

Here's the example:

`X` : empty space
`B` : a human barbarian with move speed 6 who is already in the rage of thunder hooves
`E` : a medium enemy

Initial positions:

```
XBEXX
```

Barbarian uses a move action to move 2 spaces through the enemy position to here:

```
XXEBX
```

… and then through the enemy space again to here:

```
XBEXX
```

… and then back again to here:

```
XXEBX
```

Does the barbarian get +3[W] to the following attack against this enemy? That's how I'm reading it.

Has this been errata'd? If hasn't been errata'd, was it intended to do this, or am I breaking it here?

Comment: thanks for the formatting SevenSidedDie. it's much clearer now and still accurately reflects my original intent for the question.

Comment: No problem! It's what I do 'round here. :)

Answer (score 4):

The power does not specify "**Each time** you move through an enemy's space...", only "**When** you move through...". Sounds like a boolean statement to me: either you have moved through an enemy's space or you haven't - doesn't matter if you move through it once or fifty times in a round.

Comment: +1 Exactly what I was thinking. That's a great way to express it.

Comment: that distinction that you draw between "when" and "each time" to make sound like a single trigger; there's a similar one to be drawn between "when" and "if" to make it sound like a multi-trigger. it might be my MTG background, but when I see "when" I think as triggering once if all of the triggers are simultaneous and triggering multiple times if the triggers can be placed in a chronological sequence. and squares of movement (and therefore anything triggered by different squares of the same movement) are a chronological sequence.

Comment: @Keegan - I have never encountered a rule in *any* edition, especially 4e, that did not specifically state "Each time" (or some variant) when it was meant to work that way. However, I am quite open to being wrong - I will be the first to admit I am not as familiar with 4e as of late.

Comment: Similar enough to this to not be worth putting in a separate answer:  Even if you do count it as triggering each time you go over the only thing running over them gives is the boolean state of 1[W] extra damage on the next attack (which most likely happens after your full move).  Note that (while slightly different in this case) bonuses don't stack if they're triggered from the same power/feat so it's unlikely that you are expected to be able to stack doing 1[W] extra damage three times from the same power.